# How to make the MacOS app fully transparent, while flutter widget within is fully visible?

Tags: swift, flutter, macos, dart, transparency

I do have a basic Flutter application and would like to achieve the following goals for the macOS container app:

- To make the **macOS container app** 100% **transparent** with opacity 0.
- To make the Flutter widget inside the macOS container app **100% opaque** with white background.

The idea is to have a macOS drawing app that ONLY plays as a fully transparent container, without headers, or borders, while completely seethrough and clickthrough.  The flutter app will have a tiny menu on the side and can draw anywhere on the desktop.

The following code works, **except** that the macOS app makes the flutter widget also transparent.

```swift
// appDelegate.swift

import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

````swift
// MainFlutterWindow.swift
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

class MainFlutterWindow: NSWindow {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController.init()
    let windowFrame = self.frame
    self.contentViewController = flutterViewController
    self.setFrame(windowFrame, display: true)

    RegisterGeneratedPlugins(registry: flutterViewController)

    super.awakeFromNib()
    // make the window transparent
    isOpaque = false
    backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    
  }
}

```dart
// main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, World!',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_acrylic

and set:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    Window.setEffect(effect: WindowEffect.transparent);
    Window.makeWindowFullyTransparent();
    Window.enableFullSizeContentView();
    Window.exitFullscreen();
    // Window.hideWindowControls();


    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: DrawPainter(),
        child: Container(
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Check that the scaffold must have this property `backgroundColor`

Comment: We spent a ton of time with flutter_acrylic without any success. Documentation is lacking, and beyond the demo, nothing worked.

Comment: It is working for me now, why yours does not?